# Calculating Percent Change in R for Multiple Variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate percent change in R with each of the time points included in the column label (table below). I have dplyr loaded and my dataset was loaded in R and I named it data. Below is the code I'm using but it's not calculating correctly. I want to create a new dataframe called data_per_chg which contains the percent change from "v1"  each variable from. For instance, for wbc variable, I would like to calculate percent change of wbc.v1 from wbc.v1, wbc.v2 from wbc.v1, wbc.v3 from wbc.v1, etc, and do that for all the remaining variables in my dataset. I'm assuming I can probably use a loop to easily do this but I'm pretty new to R so I'm not quite sure how proceed. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

| id | wbc.v1 | wbc.v2 | wbc.v3 | rbc.v1 | rbc.v2 | rbc.v3 | hct.v1 | hct.v2 | hct.v3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 23 | 63 | 30 | 23 | 56 | 90 | 13 | 89 | 47 |
| a2 | 81 | 45 | 46 | N/A | 18 | 78 | 14 | 45 | 22 |
| a3 | NA | 27 | 14 | 29 | 67 | 46 | 37 | 34 | 33 |

```
 data_per_chg<-data%>%
      group_by(id%>%
      arrange(id)%>%
      mutate(change=(wbc.v2-wbc.v1)/(wbc.v1))
    data_per_chg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `NA` values are all `NA` and no `N/A`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data <- data %>%
   na_if("N/A") %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
   mutate(across(-c(id, matches("\\.v1$")), ~ {
    v1 <- get(str_replace(cur_column(), "v\\d+$", "v1"))
   (.x - v1)/v1}, .names = "{.col}_change"))
```

-output

```
data
 id wbc.v1 wbc.v2 wbc.v3 rbc.v1 rbc.v2 rbc.v3 hct.v1 hct.v2 hct.v3 wbc.v2_change wbc.v3_change rbc.v2_change rbc.v3_change hct.v2_change hct.v3_change
1 a1     23     63     30     23     56     90     13     89     47     1.7391304     0.3043478      1.434783     2.9130435    5.84615385     2.6153846
2 a2     81     45     46     NA     18     78     14     45     22    -0.4444444    -0.4320988            NA            NA    2.21428571     0.5714286
3 a3     NA     27     14     29     67     46     37     34     33            NA            NA      1.310345     0.5862069   -0.08108108    -0.1081081
```

---

If we want to keep the 'v1' columns as well

```
data %>%
   na_if("N/A") %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
   mutate(across(ends_with('.v1'), ~ .x - .x, 
    .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'v1', 'v1change')}")) %>% 
   transmute(id, across(ends_with('change')),
    across(-c(id, matches("\\.v1$"), ends_with('change')),
     ~ {
    v1 <- get(str_replace(cur_column(), "v\\d+$", "v1"))
   (.x - v1)/v1}, .names = "{.col}_change")) %>%
    select(id, starts_with('wbc'), starts_with('rbc'), starts_with('hct'))
```

-output

```
 id wbc.v1change wbc.v2_change wbc.v3_change rbc.v1change rbc.v2_change rbc.v3_change hct.v1change hct.v2_change hct.v3_change
1 a1            0     1.7391304     0.3043478            0      1.434783     2.9130435            0    5.84615385     2.6153846
2 a2            0    -0.4444444    -0.4320988           NA            NA            NA            0    2.21428571     0.5714286
3 a3           NA            NA            NA            0      1.310345     0.5862069            0   -0.08108108    -0.1081081
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(id = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), wbc.v1 = c(23L, 81L, 
NA), wbc.v2 = c(63L, 45L, 27L), wbc.v3 = c(30L, 46L, 14L), rbc.v1 = c("23", 
"N/A", "29"), rbc.v2 = c(56L, 18L, 67L), rbc.v3 = c(90L, 78L, 
46L), hct.v1 = c(13L, 14L, 37L), hct.v2 = c(89L, 45L, 34L), hct.v3 = c(47L, 
22L, 33L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: thank you for such prompt response. Is there an way I can store the differences in a dataframe by itself?

Comment: @AfiaA if you don't want to update to original data, change the `mutate` to `transmute` and assign the output to a new one ie. `newdata <- data %>%
   na_if("N/A") %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
   transmute(across(-c(id, matches("\\.v1$")), ~ {
    v1 <- get(str_replace(cur_column(), "v\\d+$", "v1"));
   (.x - v1)/v1}, .names = "{.col}_change"))`

Comment: this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you! One quick question: my "id" column is now missing from the newdata. Can I just insert a new column into the newdata dataframe called "id"?

Comment: @AfiaA you can use `transmute(id, across(...`

Comment: @AfiaA try the update in my post